# PHP Ajax Curl Multithread

Tags: php, ajax, multithreading

I have 3 API (www.api1.com, www.api2.com, www.api3.com) that must be called via ajax curl, now is working fine, but I realized that while api1 not done the api2 process will be waiting until the api1 is done, so how can i make it being parallel call (the fastest will be shown)?

Note : I mean, I have some funcion in PHP that execute Curl and the function is called via ajax.

Comment: Ajax or PHP? Ajax is JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using apache, than it may be a config issue. Look into apache multithreading. Nginx may be better suited, but i'm not an expert in the multithreading part yet. I have no issues doing this with Nginx, I have many virtual servers setup that run simultaneously. If XDEBUG has been established and is monitoring each virtual web server, it will prevent them from running simultaneously.

There is no such thing as ajax curl. Each browser will implement ajax differently, and curl may be used under the hood, but it's confusing to say ajax curl. You use ajax with javascript, and likely use curl (or an abstraction to curl like Guzzle) on the server side to communicate with other servers.

Answer (score 0):

[mpyw/co](https://github.com/mpyw/co) provides the very simple, cURL and Generator based solution.

```
function curl_init_with($url, array $options = [CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true])
{
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
    return $ch;
}
```

## Example

#### Parallely execute 3 cURL requests to join with their results

```
$results = Co::wait([
    curl_init_with('www.api1.com'),
    curl_init_with('www.api2.com'),
    curl_init_with('www.api3.com'),
]);
```

#### Parallely execute 2 generators those contain cURL requests

```
Co::wait([
    function () {
        var_dump(yield [
            curl_init_with('www.api1.com'),
            curl_init_with('www.api2.com'),
            curl_init_with('www.api3.com'),
        ]);
    },
    function () {
        var_dump(yield [
            curl_init_with('www.api4.com'),
            curl_init_with('www.api5.com'),
            curl_init_with('www.api6.com'),
        ]);
    },
]);
```